# Boost thread library version mismatch

Tags: multithreading, winforms, boost, linker-errors, managed-c++

I've created a managed C++ log parser application using C++ vectors and Winforms. I want to add multithreading and Boost seemed like a better option than Winforms BackgroundWorker because I want to be able to execute my existing C++ function with each thread. I installed Boost multiple times following multiple different tutorials (lastly this one: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-definite-guide-on-compiling-and-linking-boost-c-libraries-for-visual-studio-projects-c79464d7282d) and I still have the same issue when I try to #include <boost/thread.hpp>

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib'

I don't know why it's looking for this library when I have Boost 1_79 installed not 1_78. My .lib file also has "mt-gd-x64" not just "mt-x64". I've already specified the correct file path to the library in Project->Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories. I've also tried installing Boost via Visual Studio 2022 NuGet Package Manager. The lib file in that folder is also slightly off. "vc120" instead of "vc143". I've even tried changing the .lib file name to match the file name in the linker error exactly but when I do that I get more errors like LNK1104   cannot open file 'libboost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib'

Do I just need to delete all my Boost files and download version 1_78 and try again? Why is Visual Studio looking for the wrong file name when it compiles? Is my #include statement wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by downloading boost 1_78, building it, and specifying that folder instead or the 1_79 folder. If anyone might know why the program was looking for 1_78 instead of 1_79 feel free to respond Also big thanks to George Gkasdrogkas who wrote the tutorial that worked best for me on how to install Boost. Tutorial is linked in the question :)